# Django Content-Disposition not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to build a functionality with Django, Gunicorn and Nginx where a user can request for a pdf download by submitting their email, after which a custom download link will be sent to their email. Clicking on the custom link should prompt the user to download the pdf. However, I keep getting "Page not found error".

#### Below is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
import string
import random

class BrochureToken(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)  
    token = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)  # Random token
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # Flag to track if the token has been used

    def generate_token(self):
        length = 20
        chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        self.token = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(length))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Generate token before saving if it's not already set
        if not self.token:
            self.generate_token()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

#### Below is my views.py file:

```
class BrochreRequest(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = BrochureToken.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrochureSerializers
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        serializer = BrochureSerializers(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("Serializer is valid")
            serializer.save()
            email = request.data.get("email")
            token, created = BrochureToken.objects.get_or_create(defaults={'email': email})
            download_link = f'https://api.mysite.com/api/filedownload/brochure/{token.token}'
          

            send_mail(
            'Download The OIC Brochure',
            f'Click the link to download the brochure: {download_link}',
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [email],
            fail_silently=False
        )
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



def brochure_download_view(request, token):
    download_token = get_object_or_404(BrochureToken, token=token)
    if not download_token.is_used:
        download_token.is_used = True
        download_token.save()

        # Set the file path to your actual PDF location
        file_path = 'https://api.mysite.com/media/pdfs/oic_brochure.pdf'
    

        try:
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                response = FileResponse(f, content_type='application/pdf')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename=oic_brochure.pdf'
                return response
        except FileNotFoundError:
            raise Http404("File not found")
        except SuspiciousFileOperation as e:
            raise PermissionError(f"Error opening file: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            # Log unexpected errors for debugging
            logger.error(f"Unexpected error during file download: {e}")
            return HttpResponse("Internal server error", status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

#### Below is my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import brochure_download_view, BrochreRequest

app_name = 'filedownloads'

urlpatterns = [
    path('brochure/<str:token>', brochure_download_view, name="brochure"),
    path('brochure/', BrochreRequest.as_view()),
]
```

## UPDATE

#### Below is my project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

 #FILE DOWNLOADS
    path('api/filedownload/', include('filedownloads.urls')),
]
```

##### Below is my Nginx Confiuration for mysite.com

```
server {
    server_name api.example.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /statickfiles/ {
        root /var/www/oicnm-backend;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/api/media/;
        autoindex off;  # Prevents directory listing
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Expires 0;
        
        }



    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;


        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://www.example.com' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,X-Amz-Date';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://www.example.com' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
           add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
        }

       if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://www.example.com' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
```

Comment: Check if your token saved in db & `brochure_download_view(request, token)` token in parameter are same

Comment: @AnkitTiwari  I just checked and they are the same. But What I noticed is that the custom link sent to the email is not also changing to the actual file link, and not propmting the user to download the file, hence the 404 error.

Comment: Have you set media configuration correctly?. You're using `/api/filedownload/brochure/{token}` but I don't see `api` mentioned anywhere in `urls.py`. Please provide relevant code in post

Comment: I have updated the question with more information for clarity including Nginx config.  The file to be served is located in my media directory and its URL is working properly when visited from any browser, but not working with this functionality. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Is token same everytime you send an email?, try to visit url manually greate a `BrochureToken` & then type your url with newly generated token check if it's still giving you 404.

Comment: The token is not the same. It's random.  I've just done what you suggested and I still got 404. And after visiting the url with the  token manually, ```token.Is_used``` was set to true as expected.

Comment: The app is deployed with Github Runner. I suspect the issue is permission-related. Although the workflow still runs successfully, making migrations, restarting server Gunicorn, etc from the workflow still works. What do you suggest, please? As I earlier said, the file URL works perfectly when visited with any browser.

Comment: Whats the status of gunicorn & nginx service try this command for gunicorn service log `journalctl -u your_service`

Comment: Gunicorn seems to be running fine when I ran : ```sudo systemctl status gunicorn```
``` Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-02-27 12:52:18 UTC; 58min ag```

Comment: Join [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256997/discussion-between-ankit-tiwari-and-devolamitech)